# Elastic Search: Find Boundary between And/OR documents

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, lucene

I am using below bool query to find documents that contain either of the pattern "Hello" or "World". And I am giving a boost of 2 to the AND query to make sure that the documents that contain both the tokens i.e. "Hello" and "World" are listed first(Have higher score)

```
        {:bool=>{
        :should=>[
          {
              :query_string=>{
                :query=>term
              }
          },

          {
              :query_string=>{
                :query=>term,
                :default_operator=>"AND",
                :boost=>2
              }


          }
        ],
     :minimum_should_match=>1
        }}
```

The above query serves my purpose. There might be other ways of doing it . But that is Ok. My main concern now is that once I get the result set from the above query I want to know how many documents starting from top are the AND documents i.e. (Containing both the tokens) and how many of them are the OR documents i.e. (Containing one of the tokens).

I want to find that boundary/seperation between AND/OR documents in the result set.

Any ideas.

Comment: usage of explain feature is one possiblity.

Comment: Can you fill out that query with actual terms?  I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding what your doing.  The way you've written it here, it looks like your default_operator is not having any effect, and your boost is just serving to boost results on the second term.

Comment: Generically if i search for "Hello World", Elastic search will return documents having "Hello" or "World". Now this result set will also contain documents having both "Hello" AND "World" for obvious reasons.
Now I want to find the documents which have both the tokens. On a high level, I want to know how many of the documents in the result set are AND documents and how many of them are "OR" docs.....